# GNU make: colorized output with $(info)?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Colorized output from the recipes with echo works fine. However, $(info) does not seem to work with the GNU make in sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/.

This is what I do. The weird characters are actual escapes, 0x1b.
[image]

And this is what happens. There are left arrows printed instead of the escape characters, and the ANSI color sequence is printed to the console as plain text without processing.
[image]

It works with the GNU make in Cygwin, MSYS, MinGW, GnuWin, with many versions from 3.86 to 4.3. Only the ezwinports version fails.
[image]

Is there a better way to colorize the $(info) messages? Any idea why ezwinports behaves differently?

Comment: I don't think that this has to do with `make`. See here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159718/programmatically-detect-the-ansi-escape-code-supported-by-terminal and also https://gist.github.com/mxmerz/92e97cd27857a9ba787b

Comment: It's definitely not the GNU make core, and not the terminal, either. Other POSIX layers work fine with the same make version and terminal. It must be something with the ezwinports implementation of GNU make. I know that adding the escape character directly into a text file is not a good idea, hoped that there is a better solution. Checking your links. They're useful and interesting but it seems don't solve the issue.

Comment: At the same terminal from which you issue the `make` command try `echo -e '\x1b[31mThis should be red\x1b[0m\n'`: do you see the desired output?

Comment: Yes it works in echo, but not from GNU make in ezwinports using the $(info) function.

Comment: Please try `ASCII-ESC := $(shell echo -e \e)#     escape` and `$(info $(ASCII-ESC)[1;3;47mColored output)` if this does any good.

Comment: Hmm... It seems that the make in ezwinports always translates esc to a left arrow. Got exactly the same output as with directly entering the esc char into the makefile. Might be an issue with ezwinports itself as everything works with any other make implementations. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:

```
$(shell echo 1>&2 -e "\e[31mThis is Red\e[0mThis is not")
```

Entering the esc chars directly in the text editor also works. Inserting as picture here because the esc are invisible otherwise:

[image]

A bit slower, but works with ezwinports and Chocolatey, too.
Issue finally solved!